# How do I store HCl safely?

Tags: acid-base, safety

I'm in a textile unit, where we use different chemicals. My question is what type of material should I make my tank out of to store my hydrochloric acid?

Comment: Well, it's typically stored in glass bottles :) You want bigger container?

Comment: You should always have secondary containment (e.g., a deep tray) so that any spill will be contained. Redundancy is important in safe chemical storage.

Comment: How strong is your HCl?

Answer (score 1):

This question is related: [Handling and storing sodium hydroxide, hydrochloric acid, hydrogen peroxide and isopropyl alcohol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/662/handling-and-storing-sodium-hydroxide-hydrochloric-acid-hydrogen-peroxide-and/665#665)

In the industries the handling of chemicals maybe periodic and, with routine, one tends to forget the hazardous and risks related to this. There's a lot of information on the web (http://water.usgs.gov/admin/memo/policy/wrdpolicy94.006.html):

*STORAGE: Hydrochloric acid should be kept in a tightly closed container and
stored in chemical area that is compatible with other chemicals.
Store in a secure, well-ventilated area, that is well marked, and
away from the general work population.  Do not store near oxidizing
materials.*

This manual should be helpfull too: http://www.jsia.gr.jp/data/handling_02e.pdf

*1. Types of Containers:*
*The shipping containers used for hydrochloric acid are those rail tanks be tightly sealed, such as acid-resistant bottles (including polyethylene containers, etc.), and steel drums tank trucks, tank cars, and tankers with corrosion resistant linings*

If you keep reading the manual there is valuable information about handling, transportation, and rules to keep the human safety.